# how to add unit price/individual price on woocommerce email order details

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

Hi anyone can help me how to add unit price or the individual price on woocommerce email order details? on my order details its display only product image, product name, qty, and the total price of the item like the picture below. I am using woocommerce 3.4.2

thanks in advance guys[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/froBe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the template `email-order-items.php`. Copy `email-order-items.php` file from `woocommerce\templates\emails` and paste into your theme's `woocommerce\emails` and here you can customize the product details.